# Организация Domain events с помощью ZF EventManager

Tags: php, события, zend-framework

Возможно ли организовать [модель доменных событий](https://github.com/php-ddd/domain-event) используя возможности [ZF-EventManager](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-eventmanager)?

В общем смысле, проблема заключается в инъекции зависимости от SharedEventManager для объектов домена:

```
<?php
class Order{
  private $eventManager;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->eventManager = new EventManager;

    $this->eventManager->trigger(new CreateOrderEvent);
  }
}

// Здесь приложение должно иметь возможность перехвата выброшенного события CreateOrderEvent
$order = new Order;
```

Пример демонстрирует проблему, связанную с недоступностью менеджера событий для регистрации обработчиков на нем.

Возможно аккумулировать все выброшенные объектом события в нем же (либо в менеджере) с последующим повторным выбросом их для обработки приложением:

```
<?php
$order = new Order;
$order->getEventManager()->attach(...); // Установка обработчиков уровня приложения
$events = $order->getEventManager()->pullEvents();
$app->getEventManager()->trigger($events); // Повторный выброс событий на уровне приложения
```

Приемлем ли подобный подход, или есть решение проще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одним из хороших вариантов решения задачи, на мой взгляд, является обертка над очередью с реализацией интерфейса ListenerAggregateInterface фреймворка.

Реализация очереди:

```
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManager;
use Zend\EventManager\EventsCapableInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\AbstractListenerAggregate;

class EventsKeeper extends AbstractListenerAggregate implements IteratorAggregate{
  /**
   * @var EventInterface[]
   */
  protected $eventsQueue;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->eventsQueue = new SplQueue;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1){
    $this->listeners[] = $events->attach('*', [$this, 'onEvent']);
  }

  public function onEvent(EventInterface $event){
    $this->eventsQueue->enqueue($event);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getIterator(){
    $iterator = $this->eventsQueue;
    $this->eventsQueue = new SplQueue;

    return $iterator;
  }
}
```

Пример шины событий:

```
class EventsBus{
  public function trigger(Iterator $events){
    foreach($events as $event){
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Пример использования очереди сущностью:

```
class Entity implements EventsCapableInterface{
  /**
   * @var EventManagerInterface
   */
  protected $events;

  /**
   * @var EventsKeeper
   */
  protected $eventsKeeper;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getEventManager(){
    if(!$this->events instanceof EventManagerInterface){
        $this->events = new EventManager;
        $this->eventsKeeper = new EventsKeeper;
        $this->eventsKeeper->attach($this->events);
    }

    return $this->events;
  }

  public function getEventsKeeper(){
    if(!$this->eventsKeeper instanceof EventsKeeper){
      $this->getEventManager();
    }

    return $this->eventsKeeper->getIterator();
  }

  public function foo(){
    $this->getEventManager()->trigger('Event');
  }
}
```

Пример использования очереди сущности:

```
$entity = new Entity;
$entity->foo();

$eventsBus = new EventsBus;
$eventsBus->trigger($entity->getEventsKeeper());
```